# подскажите, как СДЕЛАТЬ ЧАСЫ С ПРОГРЕСС-БАРОМ на джаваскрипте, то есть 23:59:59 = 100% и 00:00:00 = 0% (p.s. время берётся с устройства пользователя)

Tags: javascript, html

Я нуль в js пока что, заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: На данном портале люди помогают тем, кто пытается разобраться и стремиться хоть что-то сделать сам, а не чтобы за него всё сделали. За такое наказывают. Так же не стоит создавать по несколько одинаковых вопросов. Так как Вы новый участник - добавил пример получения процента времени от текущего дня, но подобные сообщения будут просто закрываться и удаляться. Имейте ввиду. Это не портал выполнения задач за Вас.

Comment: большое спасибо, что помогли. Денис, я понимаю это, в интернете не нашёл результатов (наверное плохо искал или искал не так), но спасибо за помощь. Думаю, в этом нет страшного, что кто-либо может помочь, ведь так я смогу понять как это работает (если разберусь) и другие люди, которые будут искать ответ на этот вопрос смогут увидеть ваше решение. Даже Вы, когда научились решать похожие задачи учились на примерах других, а также на своих ошибках. Не вижу ничего плохого в том, что тот, кто захочет - может объяснить и тот, кто захочет может по его/её примеру понять, что искал

Comment: Вы отчасти правы, но уже давно идёт обсуждение на meta.stackoverflow.com относительно этого момента. Очень много людей пренебрегает помощью им, лишний раз даже не прикладывая собственных усилий, чтобы понять и решить задачу. Я не имею ввиду Вас, а в подавляющем большинстве. В случае, если человек пишет **я попробовал так - не вышло**, **постарался  сделать это...** то конечно на такой вопрос Вам обязательно ответят и помогут. Вы поймите правильно. Люди не стараются решать задачи, а просто ищут ответ в интернете, что плохо. Это, своего рода, медвежья услуга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var date = new Date(); // Получаем текущую дату и время
    var hours = date.getHours(); // Получаем часы
    var mins = date.getMinutes(); // Получаем минуты
    var seconds = date.getSeconds() // Получаем секунды

    var InSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (mins * 60) + seconds; // Переводим часы и минуты в секунды
    var n = Math.floor((InSeconds * 100) / 86400) + '%'; // В дне 86400 секунд. Высчитываем процент текущего времени и добавляем вконце символ %
    
    alert(n); // Собственно показываем значение
```

Comment: а почему секунды в расчете не учитываются?

Comment: @Grundy Ну было предположение, что секунды не могут сильно повлиять на процент. Но сейчас добавлю, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function progress() {
  // начало дня
  let startTime
  const setStart = () => (startTime = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
  setStart()
  // ... конец = startTime + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  const inputRange = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  const p = () => 100 / (inputRange / (Date.now() - startTime))
  
  return () => {
    let t = p()
    if (t > 100) {
      setStart()
      t = p()
    }
    console.log(t)
  }
}

setInterval(progress(), 1000)
```